# Remove hard/blocked bounces

Tags: marketing-cloud, bounce-management

I have SQL in place now but it is not excluding any bounces. Can you help me add a bounce SQL query in it?
My current query in place for the list I want to pull.

```sql
select email, max(date_added) as date_added 
from [DE] 
Where email not like '%@company.com'
group by email
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to reference the _Bounce Dataview to get this info. The below is based on that 'email' field from your DE is equal to your subscriberkey. You may need to adjust this depending on what field is your sendable field.

```sql
SELECT a.email, max(a.date_added) as date_added
FROM [DE] a
WHERE a.email not like '%@company.com'
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT TOP 1 b.Subscriberkey
  FROM [_Bounce] b
  WHERE b.Subscriberkey = a.email
  AND b.BounceCategory IN ('Hard bounce','Block bounce')
)
group by a.email
```

The NOT EXISTS will remove any records that have a hard or block bounce that is recorded in your Bounce Dataview.